# Some trouble with python scope and objects

Tags: python

```
class Thing:
    def __init__ (self, a, b, c,):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

stuff = Thing("apples","butter","charlie")
otherThing = stuff

def doTheThings():
    if(otherThing.a == "apples"):
        print("done")

doTheThings()
```

I'm having a problem with the second line of the "doTheThings" function, and I have no idea what's wrong. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "having a problem"?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What is the error ?, I have tried your code and I have not had problems.

Answer (score -2):

I think add somthing maybe solve your problem.

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
      doTheThings()
```

beacuse this is access of python code.

Comment: "beacuse this is access of python code.", No it's not always true.